# Generate .msg file for Outlook

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, msg

Is there a way to have Javascript/jQuery (or any other web-based language) generate a .msg file that also has an attachment?

I am trying to make it so when a user clicks a button, it downloads a .msg file that has Subject/Body filled out and has a file attached. I know I can just use a long `mailto:` link but that would not let me attach a file.

Comment: .msg is only supported in outlook I guess... What if users don't have outlook?

Comment: This is something I only want to work in Outlook.

Comment: Did you already try to make something? Perhaps in PHP? If so, please provide some code.

Comment: My code is pointless because it just creates a string for the body. The thing I need assistance with is actually creating a .msg file.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to pass such content due to both protocol and security measures. Also there is no way to know how each browser is setup to react to the mailto address (Outlook, Webmail, Nothing)..

If you want to send emails with a prefilled subject or content then I suggest you handle it server side with PHP or equivalent language. A great library to consider is SwiftMail

Good Luck

Comment: I found msgkit to work very well for my .net project. https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit